# Failure binding Angular promise to $scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem binding a promise to `<autocomplete source='fnPromise()'>` when using ngTagsInput. I don't think there is anything wrong with [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted); I think I don't understand scope and promises well enough to understand how to do what I want to do.

I set up the directive normally:

```
<tags-input ng-model="token.ids.tags"
            class="form-field no-animate tag-input"
            placeholder="Delete unwanted IDs"
            addFromAutocompleteOnly="true">
    <auto-complete source="offerTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

The problem lies in the offerTags() function. This returns a promise, but because I want to populate the autocomplete with the array that's part of this controller's $scope, I tell the promise just returns that $scope attribute:

```
$scope.offerTags=function(query) {
    var deferred=$q.defer();

    var tags=$scope.token.ids.tags;
    deferred.resolve( tags);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

However, $scope.token.ids.tags is only populated after a service has returned (after the page has loaded). So what happens is that offerTags always returns an empty array. The promise is not updated with the new values of token.ids.tags service.

EDIT: [Plunkr demonstrating problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Xurq1?p=preview)

I.e., if you replace the $scope.token.ids.tags with a static array, then the autocomplete functionality works, but only the contents of that static array.

Sorry for the long explanation... any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Can we see the service? is it returning a promise?

Comment: `offerTags` (quoted above) is the service that returns the promise. `$scope.token.ids.tags` is updated in various places as a callback to an $http request.

Comment: I guess ngTagsInput is a red herring here - the problem is that the promise does not reflect the changing value of $scope.

Comment: Please post more code or a plunker

Comment: Ok, will do. I can't now reproduce my problem in a plunkr so something is up... brb.

Comment: @IlanFrumer plunkr added. It's definitely the updating of scope inside a service callback that causes the problem. If scope is updated outside the service, autocomplete updates fine.

Comment: You plunker is broken.

Comment: Works fine for me. a) type some stuff into field, see auto complete values. Press Change Autocomplete List, and try again - see auto complete values are not updated.

Comment: you frustrating me. Look at the console: `ReferenceError: TokenService is not defined`, I need to see the relevant code , i cannot guess how it looks, the service in the plunker is just a mock

Comment: I am also frustrated. I updated the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Xurq1?p=preview but still get that error (apologies this my first plunkr). There is nothing wrong with the definition of TokenService that I can see.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/RXDHmY?p=preview
Just updated

Comment: Ok, I forgot to inject my service. :) But your example does not test my scenario. I updated mine: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Xurq1?p=preview

Comment: You lack the basic understanding of what promises are

Comment: Ok I am going to agree with you there. I fixed my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4Xurq1?p=preview and problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your service should look similar to this:

```
app.factory('TokenService', function ($http) {
    return {
        loadTags: function (query) {
          return $http.get('/query', {
            params: {
             q: query
            }
          }).then(function(res){
            return res.data;
          });
        }
    }
});
```

Put it on the scope:

```
$scope.loadTags = TokenService.loadTags;
```

And the template:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```